# Is there a way to combine Java8 Optional returning a value with printing a message on null?

Tags: java, java-8, null, option-type

I'm starting with this code:

```
String startingValue = getMyValue();
String finishingValue = "";
if (startingValue != null) {
    finishingValue = startingValue;
} else {
    System.out.println("Value was null");
}
```

I want to transform it using Java 8 options to something like this:

```
Optional<String> startingOptional = getMyOptional();
String finishingValue =
        startingOptional
                .map(value -> value)
                .orElse(System.out.println("value not found"));
```

My question is: **Is there a way to combine Java8 Optional returning a value with printing a message on null?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `orElseGet`:

```
Optional<String> startingOptional = getMyOptional();
String finishingValue = startingOptional.orElseGet(() -> {
    System.out.println("value not found");
    return "";
});
```

Using `.map(value -> value)` is useless: transforming a value into itself doesn't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Java 9 or later and you don't want to use default stub for empty value but instead handle empty and non-empty cases separately, you can also use `Optional#ifPresentOrElse(Consumer, Runnable)` method whose second argument is the handler for empty value.
For your case it would look like:

```java
Optional<String> startingOptional = getMyOptional();
startingOptional
        .map(value -> value)
        .ifPresentOrElse(
                value -> {/* do something with your value */},
                () -> System.out.println("value not found")
        );
```

or, ommiting the local variable:

```java
getMyOptional()
        .map(value -> value)
        .ifPresentOrElse(
                value -> {/* do something with your value */},
                () -> System.out.println("value not found")
        );
```

Comment: ifPresentOrElse returns void. So the first snippet wouldn't compile. And the map operation is useless.

Comment: My mistake, fixed it