# Is there a way to combine Java8 Optional returning a transformed value with printing a message on null?

Tags: java, java-8, null, option-type

I'm starting with this code:

```
String startingValue = getMyValue();
List<String finishingValue = new ArrayList;
if (startingValue != null) {
    finishingValue = Arrays.asList(startingValue.split());
} else {
    System.out.println("Value was null");
}
```

I want to transform it using Java 8 options to something like this:

```
Optional<String> startingOptional = getMyOptional();
List finishingValue =
        startingOptional
                .map(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split(",")))
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    System.out.println("value not found"); 
                    return "";
                });
```

Now I can do this - but it doesn't really make it simpler.

```
    Optional<String> startingValue = getMyValue();
    String finishingValue = startingValue
            .orElseGet(() -> {
        System.out.println("value not found");
        return "";
    });
    List<String> finishingValueList = new ArrayList();
    if (startingValue.isPresent()) {
        finishingValueArray = startingValue.get().split(",");
        finishingValueList = Arrays.asList(finishingValueArray);
    }
```

My question is: **Is there a way to combine Java8 Optional returning a value with printing a message on null?**

Note this is different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59517743/is-there-a-way-to-combine-java8-optional-returning-a-value-with-printing-a-messa/59518158#59518158) as I'm doing an additional transformation in the value is present case.

Comment: In `orElseGet` return empty `List` instead of string, like `new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: A more proper use of `Optional` would be to either use `orElseGet` to return an empty list & check if the list is empty to trigger the message (wouldn't need to return null, the thing `Optional` is designed to avoid) or to use `orElseThrow` to indicate the presence of the issue.

Comment: Note: You cannot do `startingValue.orElseGet` for a String type as in your last code block.

Comment: Also, a better design for such use cases would be to change the return type of `getMyValue()` to follow the signature `Optional<String> getMyValue()`. Otherwise, your first code block was good enough to handle `null`.

Comment: Thanks @Naman - that's helpful, I've updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Deadpool (great name!):

```
import java.util.*;

class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        Optional<String> startingOptional = Optional.ofNullable(null);
        List<String> finishingValue =
                startingOptional
                    .map(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split(",")))
                    .orElseGet(() -> {
                        System.out.println("value not found"); 
                        return new ArrayList<String>();
                    });
        System.out.println("finishingValue: " + finishingValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Collections.emptyList()` instead of `new ArrayList<>()` if the returned value isn't mutated.

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this works for you

```
String startingValue = getMyValue();
return Optional.ofNullable(startingValue)
               .map(value ->Arrays.asList(startingValue.split(",")))
               .orElseGet(()->{
                   System.out.println("Value was null");
                   return null;
                });
```